# convex hull of the set of permutations with one cycle

Tags: convex-polytopes, permutations

is there a way to describe the convex hull of the set of permutation matrices with exactly one non-trivial cycle?

or maybe I should ask for the convex hull of cycle matrices :

let $(i_{1},..,i_{k})$ be a cycle then $A$ is a cycle matrix if  the entries $(i_{1},i_{2})$ ...$(i_{k},i_{1})$ are $1/k$, and all the others are 0.
(it seems to me that this convex hull is the set of non-negative matrices of entries sum equal to 1)

Comment: Hm, you mean similar to the Birkhoff polytope, as a nice list of inequalities and equalities?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff_polytope

Comment: Yes,a similar list of constraints..

Comment: So the matrix with a single 1 somewhere is not in the convex hull. Also the convex hull gives weight 0 to the diagonal, so the convex hull is certainly more complicated than you think.

Comment: another comment: the $i$th row and the $i$th column have the same sum for each $i$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It's exactly the collection of non-negative matrices subject to:

The entries sum to 1;

The diagonal entries are 0;

For each $i$, the $i$th column and $i$th row have equal sums.

The proof is by induction on the number of non-zero entries.
Suppose that matrices satisfying the above conditions with at most $k$ non-zero entries are in the convex hull. Then given a matrix $A$ with $k+1$ non-zero entries, pick an entry $(i,j)$ of the matrix so that $A_{ij}$ is non-zero. Let $i_0=i$ and $i_1=j$. Since the $i_1$st row has a non-zero entry, the $i_1$st column must also have a non-zero entry. Continue in this way until $i_l=i_m$ for some $l<m$. Then there is a cycle $i_l,i_{l+1},\ldots,i_m,i_l$ where all the entries corresponding to an edge are non-zero. Take the minimum of the edge-weights $w$ and let $B$ be the matrix with weights $1/(m-l)$ on the $m-l$ edges forming the cycle. Then $A=w(m-l)B+(1-w(m-1))C$ for a matrix $C$ satisfying the constraints and having at least one less non-zero entry.

Comment: But any column and any row must have sum $1/k$, yes?

Comment: I don't think so. For example if the permutation is a transposition, then there are 2 columns and rows with weight 1/2 and the rest with weight 0.

Comment: Ah, I see, this one cycle is not presumed to be "long cycle".

Comment: Thanks, can we say something about the set of increasing cycle (ie $i_{1}<i_{2}<..<i_{k}$)